# Javascript addEventListener not firing, but JQuery bind does fire on focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI ComboBox and I have looked around to try and catch a focus out event on it, but was only able to find a working example using a kendo ui dropdownlist. I modified it to work with the combobox but it never worked.
So I came up with an idea, that since it uses a textbox that I would just catch the focus out event on that.

I could catch the focus out event using JQuery like this..

```
let stateCombobox = $('#acCustomerStates');
stateCombobox.bind('focusout', function(e){
    console.log("Focus out");
});
```

But when I tried doing it with JavaScript, it wouldn't fire and I am using this..

```
let stateCombobox = document.getElementById('acCustomerStates');
stateCombobox.addEventListener('focusout', function(){
    console.log("focus out");
});
```

My question is, why is the addEventListener failing?

```js
(function() {
  var data = [{
      text: "Item1",
      value: "1"
    },
    {
      text: "Item2",
      value: "2"
    },
    {
      text: "Item3",
      value: "3"
    }
  ];

  $("#acCustomerStates").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data
  });

  // JQuery

  //let stateCombobox = $('#acCustomerStates');
  //stateCombobox.bind('focusout', function(e) {
  //  console.log("Focus out");
  //});

  //JavaScript

  //let stateCombobox = document.getElementById('acCustomerStates');
  //stateCombobox.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
  //  console.log("focus out");
  //});

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input id='acCustomerStates' />
```

Comment: If you inspect the generated element that kendo makes, that you interact with, it appears to be a different element than the one you initialized kendo on.  As such I would suspect that the initialized element is never getting focus.  Only the elements that were created/managed by kendo are getting focus, and the initialized element is just being manipulated behind the scenes as a result of the changes.

Comment: @Taplar, I understand that. My apologies if I am incorrect, but the question is why does using jquery bind event work and javascripts addEventListener doesn't with this control

Comment: It could be that kendo triggers the event with jQuery, and not with the native event.  But that's just a theory.

Comment: Mmm..maybe its coming down to a javascript equivalent of jquery's $(this) ?